# Cannot Print This PDF, Can Print Other PDFs

Tags: printing, pdf, evince, 19.04, brother

I just upgraded to 19.04. I have a Brother laser printer that I've used for quite a while with 14.04 with no problems. I reinstalled the drivers, and have been using the printer in 19.04, also without problems, to print .odt, .docx, and .pdf files.

This morning I tried to print a specific pdf. Nothing seems amiss when I click print, but the file did not print. I tried other pdfs, and they work fine. I tried another pdf reader (Okular instead of Evince) and that same file will not print from Okular either. Same if I open it in Firefox.

It's not the end of the world if I can't print this one pdf on this machine, but I am very curious about what could be causing this. Any tips on how to troubleshoot, or what might cause a single pdf to not print?

Comment: Try this: print the pdf to a file, and choose `pdf` as the file format. Then print *that* pdf file.

Comment: Would it happen to be one of those fancy ones with fill-in spaces and such? Sometimes you need the official Acrobat reader to work with those....

Comment: @AndroidDev Nope, just simple images and text. Instructions from an auto manufacturer on how to install a part.

Comment: @Jos that's a good suggestion. I tried prints as pdf and printing the output of that, but it showed the same behavior.

Comment: a year later this is still an issue, also does not work with 18.04

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the "Force rasterization" in Okular, you might be able to get around these unprintable PDFs by converting them to a 600 DPI `.djvu` file:

```
pdf2djvu -d 600 file.pdf > printable.djvu
```

or to a 600 DPI PDF 1.3 file:

```
ps2pdf13 -r600x600 file.pdf printable.pdf
```

More details can be found at https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/printing-hard-to-print-pdfs-on-linux/.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I have the same issue with a specific pdf (OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, kde, Epson printer, Okular). While I still don't know why this happens, a 'Force Rasterization'in the kde print dialog, pdf options, works around the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just lost a good forty minutes of my life on this which I will never get back.

Very, very strange. Some pdfs, the printer totally springs to life, prints all pages, double sided if you want. Other pdfs it just won't not respond, as if it is totally aloof, too good to print that pdf.

I tried `pdf2djvu` and `ps2pdf13` solutions above which did not work for the troublesome pdf.

What did work was this -

`convert -density 288 problematic.pdf unproblematic.pdf`

Imagemagick did the trick. Found that here -

https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=6599&p=2

There was another suggestion with `gs` which produced a file which would not print.

It is probably not the printer drivers. In my case I am using Debian 11 Bullseye and the printer is a Brother HL-L2340DW.  The drivers were installed with

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-brlaser
```

..but it really seems to be the peculiarity of some pdfs more than the drivers as I also experimented with drivers and patches from the brother website which did not solve it. Very peculiar I wonder what the root cause it.