# I can't print PDF files in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing, pdf, evince

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and I have trouble printing PDF files. When I start the job (be it from Evince, Okular or Chrome) the paper LED of my printer Brother (HL-L2310D) starts blinking and then nothing happens (I waited for 10 minutes). In the job overview the status of the job is "Processing".

What puzzles me is: printing for example odt or JPEG files works fine. On top of that, I have Windows installed on the same machine and printing PDF files from there works, too.

I tried printing the PDF files to PDF files first as recommended in [Cannot Print This PDF, Can Print Other PDFs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140758/cannot-print-this-pdf-can-print-other-pdfs), however, it did not help either.

Comment: did you try the comment by @Jos "Try this: print the pdf to a file, and choose pdf as the file format. Then print that pdf file."

Comment: Yes, as I already wrote.

Comment: I had almost similar problem. In my case problem was caused by imagemagick/ graphicsmagick*. check what is installed in your system and see if changing works for you. I mean if your system have imagemagick try installing  sudo apt-get install --assume-yes graphicsmagick*.